# std::copy objects read from file to a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator, copy

Here is this class I've written that has 2 variables, and the way objects will be created is going to be trough a file

```
  class CData {
int m_iTimeID;
double m_dData;

  friend istream& operator>>(istream& IS, CData* Obj){
    Obj = new CData();
    IS >> Obj->m_iTimeID >> Obj->m_dData;
    return IS;
}
```

It is supposed to be a pointer (I believe)

Now there is another class with a variable a vector of pointers of the first class

```
  class CCalc3SigmaControl {
vector<CData*> m_vectorData;
```

And a constructor that is reading data from a file (this is where my problem accures)

```
 CCalc3SigmaControl(const char* filename){

    ifstream FP(filename); 
    istream_iterator<CData*> begin_itt (FP);
            istream_iterator<CData*> end_source ;
    copy(begin_itt,end_source ,back_inserter(m_vectorData));  
}
```

**I am tasked with using the copy algorithm in this part!**

Now, all of this compiles and the program runs, but when it gets to a part that I try to get data from the vector (say like this m_vectorData[i]->getData(); ) it returns an error that it cant get the data "Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD4." and that in m_dData and ID it is "unable to read memory".

Now I set some breakpoints at the copy and the overloaded >> . The operator gets the data from the file, but when the program gets in the copy my begin_itt points to no values and it assigns nothing to the vector (just pushes backs an empty objects or something i GUESS).
And I need this copy to work!

```
  void calcSigmas(){
    sigmaUp=0;   //a private of CCalc3SigmaControl
    sigmaDown=0;  //also
    double Mean = 0;
    double n = m_vectorData.size();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    Mean = Mean + m_vectorData[i]->getData();
    }
    sigmaUp = Mean + 3 * sqrt (abs((Mean * (1 - Mean))/n));
    sigmaDown = Mean - 3 * sqrt (abs((Mean * (1 - Mean))/n));
}
```

(getData func in CData:

```
   double getData() const {                 //GET DATA
    return m_dData;}
```

)

There. In my main function I have:

```
 void main(){
 CCalc3SigmaControl A("Danni.txt");
 A.calcSigmas();
```

And when it tries to calculate them it gets the error.
This is pretty much it. And I've overloaded the << in ccalc so that I can cout the data in the main.

Comment: I'm hesitant to even consider where to begin, starting with how useful a class is where *everything* is *private*. The idea of using raw-pointers in a container not withstanding (generally an aromatic idea if there ever was one), post the code that actually *crashes*. I.e. `m_vectorData[i]->getData()` and the control mechanism for `i`, as well as the full class *declaration* for `CCalc3SigmaControl`.

Comment: Vectors of pointers require extreme care in handling. Does `CCalc3SigmaControl` have a destructor? If it does, does it also have an assignment operator and a copy constructor?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight no it doesnt. Like I edited it now with the function for the calculation. this is pretty much it.

Comment: @WhozCraig This is it - CCal3Sigma has the vectors and the 2 variables afterwards is the constructor and the calc func

Comment: `Obj = new CData();` changes the parameter, i.e. the local copy of the pointer. You need to pass the pointer *by reference*.